# OpenERP onchange result format specification?

Tags: python, events, odoo, onchange

According to the section "Views and Events" of OpenERP Documentation, the "On Change" event handler must return:

```
return {‘domain’: d, ‘value’: value, ‘warning’: warning}
```

more specifically:

*a dictionary with any mix of the following keys:*

**domain**

*A mapping of {field: domain}.*

The returned domains should be set on the fields instead of the default ones.

**value**

*A mapping of {field: value}*

the values will be set on the corresponding fields and may trigger new onchanges or attrs changes

**warning**

*A dictionary with the keys title and message.*

Both are mandatory. Indicate that an error message should be displayed to the user.

But I have seen through the code the use of some other values as **context** and **type**.

**Which are all the possible values and where is stated in the OpenERP code**?